# How to open the model space in AutoCAD so that all objects can be seen at once?

Tags: python, autocad, autocad-scripts

What function exists in AutoCAD that will allow you to open a drawing model so that you can immediately see the objects in this drawing:

now it looks like this:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bahS.png)

It needs to be like this:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wssSb.png)

tried to find a method or function in pyautocad, but couldn't find it

Comment: application.zoomextents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pyautocad, use
Application.ZoomExtents as described in the documentation
https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-B204BFAA-B774-4C87-86D8-37007F390B5A

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I can imagine is to open AutoCAD with script which evaluates command `_Zoom;_E`